# Getting crash on clicking of listview item in android

Tags: listview, android-intent, classcastexception

I have two Activities and one model class. In Activity A
i have cities named cityA, cityB, cityC and so on.
In second activity i have 7 TextViews where i am showing 
details according to city names.
Tried doing `intent.putExtra` but getting crash. Please tell
me if i am missing something.

Note : If i am clicking on cityA details should be only
from cityA.

code of Activity A

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            CityTable table1 = (CityTable)listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            String toolbartitle = table1.getAreaName();  //for toolbar
                            String population = table1.getPopulation_2015();
                            String established = table1.getYearEstablished();


 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
                            intent.putExtra("toolbartitle",toolbartitle);
                            intent.putExtra("population",population);
                            intent.putExtra("established",established);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

code of Activity B

```
 List<CityTable> tablecity= new ArrayList<>();
  tablecity.addAll((List<CityTable>) result);
 for (final CityTable city : tablecity){
 String toolbartitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString("toolbartitle");
                    String population = getIntent().getExtras().getString("population");
                    String established = getIntent().getExtras().getString("established");

    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                    textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);


   textview1.setText(population);
and so on....
```

I dont know..i am missing with position or something else, but getting crash

crash log

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.project_android.Citytable
```

Comment: Hi @Vivek, please provide type of the List you are using in the ListView.

Comment: final List<CityTable> citytable= new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Please provide code of your Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity A

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
     {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      CityTable table1 = (CityTable)listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
      ...
     }
```

> CityTable table1 = (CityTable)listView.getItemAtPosition(i);

must be the line that is causing you the crash. Your adapter list must be of one type and you are attempting to cast it into another type - CityTable.

You must make the list in the adapter of type CityTable.

Comment: this should definitely solve your problem well done.